# Using JNI / JVMTI - How to determine if jfieldID is static or not

Tags: reflection, java-native-interface, jvmti

If I use `jvmti_env->GetClassFields(objClass, &numOfFields, &fieldIds);` I still have to decide whether to call GetStatic<Type>Field or Get<Type>Field. 
How do I determine which one to use? I know that in java.lang.reflect.Field I can query fields' modifiers for static.

I've found a workaround here:
http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs433/programming/examples-java-socket/jdk1.5/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/jfieldIDWorkaround.hpp

But I prefer a solution from the JVM. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function 
[GetFieldModifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetFieldModifiers) in JVMTI.

Values returned by this function are described here:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#1480

So for static you should check like this:

```
jint accessFlags
...
(*jvmti)->GetFieldModifiers(jvmti, objClass, fieldIds[i], &accessFlags);
if (accessFlags & 0x0008)
   printf("STATIC\n");
else
   printf("NOT STATIC\n");
```